# onClick method for Buttons in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, eclipse, button, expandablelistview

My ExpandableListView has some EditText boxes and Buttons(It's a sign-in/register screen).
I want to use an onClick function with a switch case to select the button that has been clicked and do something with them.

For the Buttons, I can't set the onClickListener.

All this is in the Custom Expandable List Adapter Class than I wrote.

I know there is another way to address a normal function in a Custom Expandable List Adapter but I don't know how.

Here's the relevant snippets of code WITHIN CustomExpandableAdapter class :

```
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   v = null;
   position = 0;
   position=getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);

   * - - unrelated code - *

   if(position==2)  //Draws Forgot Button
   {
       v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forgot, parent, false);
       View forgot = v.findViewById(R.id.fpb);
       //What goes here to setOnClickListener?   
   }
   return v;
}

public void onClick(View w) {

    PopupWindow pw= new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null, false),220,160, true);;
    switch(w.getId())
    {
    case R.id.fpb:

        {       
            pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }

}
```

Can someone pleases help out??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have implemented `OnClickListner` in your adapter. If yes, then what error were you getting when using `forgot.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: I re-did the whole code and it worked. 

The final solution was to use
setOnClickListener(this); only which for some reason just wasn't working before. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty...you need to set OnClickListener not on the view, but on the specific buttons. So-you need to findViewByID(find the EditBox, Buttons or whatever) IN that `View forgot` and then set onClickListener ON them.

Such as...

```
Button b = forgot.findViewByID("myButton");
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
    etc...
```

Be sure to use the right OnClickListener, there are two in the API!:)

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. But I wanted to implement just one onClick(View v) function with a switch case for all possible buttons. Instead took the longer approach and did what you mentioned :)

Comment: No prob, just don't forget to accept the answer if you used it;)

Comment: Seems like I can't accept both answers because both are valid solutions but I ended up using the other answer!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might exist, but here's what I do:

**1. Interface**

```
import android.view.View;

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v);
}
```

**2. In your Activity/Fragment**

```
public class MyFragment(or Activity) Fragment implements RecyclerViewClickListener {
```

It will show an error that methods are not implemented. Add them

```
@Override public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v) {
    YourObject mObject = (YourObject) v.getTag();
    Log.i("My Object with >>> ", String.valueOf(mObject.getId()));
}
```

**3. In your Adapter in the consturctor add at the end**

public ExpandListViewAdapter(FragmentActivity context, etc. etc., RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener)

**4. In your Adapter in getChildView()**

```
   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
               v.setTag(YourObject);
               clickListener.recyclerViewListClicked(v);
            }
   });
```